# properly linking sqlite to Java using jdbc

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

for the past couple of hours i have been trying anything i can in order to link sqlite to my intellij IDE and its not been going well at all.

for clarification:
java version = 11.0
jdbk version = 3.44.1.0

i went through the process of downloading sqlite (64-bit windows version) and the sqlite tools i put everything into one folder and added it to PATH in my enviorment variables.
i then download jdbk put it in the same folder as the other files then went to intellij and added it into the libraries/dependencies of my project (pictures below)[image]
[image]

then i wrote a simple script to address my already made database and try to connect it, this is the script:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/userdata.db";
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);

        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and no matter what ive done so far i keep getting this same error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/userdata.db
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

i have tried running the code from the command prompt while specifying the location of userdata there and it didnt work. i can also gurantee the files are in the correct spots and that the problem isn't as simple as a typo. I'm not exactly sure whats going on here, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to download a driver from [SQLite JDBC Driver](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc#sqlite-jdbc-driver):

> SQLite JDBC is a library for accessing and creating SQLite database files in Java.
>
> Our SQLiteJDBC library requires no configuration since native libraries for major OSs, including Windows, macOS, Linux etc., are assembled into a single JAR (Java Archive) file.

Then follow the example. You can also try

```
try {
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // handle the error
}
```

If you need more information check out [What does 'Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6740601/573032)